# Could not able to scan jar file : bad magic number

Tags: java, gradle, swagger

I am trying to generate swagger from an interface in my project. I am writing a new task in gradle which assembles the specs. When trying to read a jar or scan a jar file it throws an error like

```
DEBUG org.reflections.Reflections - could not scan file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in url jar<JAR URL>

org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class object from file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Caused by: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from MANIFEST.MF
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:102)
    at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:24)
    at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:30)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone please assist me on this? This is a major blocker for my project.

Comment: in the pasted stacktrace there is nothing about bad magic number (something got truncated?) but magic number always means that the classes compiled are of higher version then the java you are trying to run it with. Please provide the exact name and version of the jar and the version of the java you are trying to run with.

Also if you look into the mentioned manifest it sometimes contains information about java used for compilation

Comment: I am using source compatible java  version as 8 in my gradle file. But I don't how to find the java version of compiled class files and also I have around 40 dependent libraries.

Comment: Well, the message states it: "could not create class object from file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" - why it tries to create a _class_ from a _text_ file would be the issue to tackle.

Comment: @Thomas unless manifest entries contain a detail of a class to be loaded such as java agent. That is why OP should look into the contents of a manifest using some standard unzipping software, or for windows by changing the extension to .zip and opening

Comment: @maslan yes, that could be the case. However, that would mean the manifest would be used to create/analyze _other_ files and not to try to create a class from the manifest itself.

Comment: @Thomas thats why we would need to see the manifest file, and the full stacktrace with causes (it is possible that simply a few lines below lies the real reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: I was using swagger core plugin 2.5.0 with java source compatibility as 8.1. Then I changed the plugin version 2.7.0, then it worked fine with no errors. Looks like 2.5.0 has some problem. Thanks guys for the response.

Comment: The swagger 1.x implementations have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use filterInputsBy which will only scan classes.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage("com.abc.service"))
            .setScanners(new TypeAnnotationsScanner())
         .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include(".*class"))
 
 );
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for your tips.
I got the same problem when using cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger 3.2.0. (dependency reflections-0.9.11.jar)
Finally needs downgrade to 3.1.13 (dependency reflections-0.9.10.jar).